# If a column is the primary key does it need to be in an index

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, indexing

I have a table that uses ENC_ID as a PK.  This field is also a FK (another table controls its creation) to a number of other tables (it is created in one of these other tables).

It has two indices:

1. IX_00 - DEPT_ID, ARRIVAL_TIME, ENC_ID - services SELECT queries; DEPT_ID, ARRIVAL_TIME in WHERE clause; ENC_ID in JOIN clause
2. IX_01 - DEPARTURE_TIME, ENC_ID - services DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE queries; DEPARTURE_TIME in WHERE clause; ENC_ID in JOIN clause

Questions:

1. Does defining ENC_ID as a PK automatically create an index?
2. Is there any value to having the ENC_ID field in either index?  Or should it be the sole column in a third index?

Answer (score 0):

> Does defining ENC_ID as a PK automatically create an index?

Yes. The PK is always backed by a unique index (if you simply declare a PK constraint on the column)

> Is there any value to having the ENC_ID field in either index

It depends on the query if e.g. the index contains all columns used in the SQL statement, then this does have a benefit as Oracle can use an index scan in that situation. If the SQL statement uses more columns than defined in the index, adding the PK column might not have any advantage.

Whether or not an index is used depends on several things (the query, the number of rows in the table, the distribution of values for the index, ...), so it's not possible to give you an general rule "this will always be used" or "this will never be used".

You might want to go through the concepts manual as well: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/indexiot.htm#BABHJAJF

Comment: "The PK is always backed by a unique index" . it can happily use a non unique index too.

Comment: @DazzaL: I knew this was coming ;) But if you just declare a column as a PK then you will wind up with a unique index.

Comment: There is no structural difference between a unique and non-unique index in Oracle. Its just that the the rowid is not considered part of the key in a unique index and in a non-unique index the rowid is considered part of the key.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name :) yep, i assumed he was talking about adding an PK to an existing table (which may have a serviceable non unique index), hence why i pointed that out.

Answer (score 0):

1. It will create an index only IF one (unique or non-unique) is not available for it to use. i.e. if you had say an index on (ENC_ID, whatever else), then adding a PK would just use that index and wouldnt create another.
2. as you're not filtering on ENC_ID and only joining then possibly not, as if your driving from that table, then the filtering columns are what you need to index (it may still have benefit depending on the query (eg if it can use another joining index to eliminate rows before table access is done). if you're driving from the other table, then it would want to use an index with ENC_ID on the leading edge. We'd need to see the SQL to provide a more definitive answer though.